# Play button not working again after clicked "Back" button

Tags: android

I loaded Interstitial Ads at onCreate method as following,

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.singlechannel_activity);

    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    mAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    mInterstitial.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.admob_intertestial_id));
    mInterstitial.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    mInterstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onAdLoaded();
        }
    });
```

And show ads trigger to Play button to show Interstitial ads before playing video.
Here is code to show ads which trigger to Play button..

```
        img_ply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (mInterstitial.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitial.show();
                mInterstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdClosed() {
                        super.onAdClosed();
                            Intent inttv = new Intent(SingleChannelActivity.this, TvPlay.class);
                            inttv.putExtra("url", ChannelUrl);
                            startActivity(inttv);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Ads show pretty fast instantly, and then proceed to video perfectly but Problem is after playing video, user click "Back" button and after that Play button doesn't working anymore and cannot click on that again. Could you please show me example how to work that button again...???

Comment: you have put your code in  if (mInterstitial.isLoaded()) condition if add is not loaded then it will not work. put one else condition place code in that also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**something like this**

```
img_ply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (mInterstitial.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitial.show();
            mInterstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdClosed() {
                    super.onAdClosed();
                        Intent inttv = new Intent(SingleChannelActivity.this, TvPlay.class);
                        inttv.putExtra("url", ChannelUrl);
                        startActivity(inttv);
                }
            });
        }else{
              Intent inttv = new Intent(SingleChannelActivity.this, TvPlay.class);
                        inttv.putExtra("url", ChannelUrl);
                        startActivity(inttv);

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks bro.... it is working... But on second click.. No ads is showing...

Comment: some time Interstitial ads are not loaded so its not showing ads if add is loaded then its shown.